# How to quote what's left of the remaining horizontal space?

Tags: line

I'm trying to come up with my own command to fill what's left of the horizontal space with dots but I want the dots slightly lowered relative to the text. Here's my code :

```
\newcommand\ansfill{\raisebox{-.2\baselineskip}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\dotfill}}}
```

This works fine when there's nothing on my line

```
\ansline
```

but goes into \hbox overfull error when I add anything as the box from \makebox is always \linewidth.

e.g.

```
Example Text \ansfill
```

gives me an overfull hbox error.

I need a parameter that changes depending on what's left of the horizontal space. Something like :

```
\newcommand\ansfill{\raisebox{-.2\baselineskip}{\makebox[\whatever-that-is-left]{\dotfill}}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove that box? `\dotfill` will fill the remaining line for you.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to be lower relative to the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can emulate the definition of `\dotfill`. I also add an optional argument to set a minimum width for the dots. The last example shows what would happen without the `[8em]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ansfill}[1][0pt]{%
  \leavevmode
  \leaders
  \hbox to 0.44em{\hss\raisebox{-2pt}{.}\hss}%
  \hskip #1 plus 1fill
  \kern0pt
}

\begin{document}

Here's a question. \ansfill

Here's another longer question for which we need at least eight ems
of space for the answer. \ansfill[8em]

Here's another longer question for which we need at least eight ems
of space for the answer, even though the line would be almost filled up
with text. \ansfill[8em]

Here's another longer question for which we need at least eight ems
of space for the answer, even though the line would be almost filled up
with text. \ansfill % <--- Uh, oh!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works exactly as expected for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The dimension `\linegoal` defined by the package of the same name is probably the right thing here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newcommand\ansfill{\raisebox{-.2\baselineskip}{\makebox[\linegoal]{\dotfill}}}

\begin{document}

This is something \ansfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "Extended allocation already in use" and the line appears to be slightly shorter than expected.

Comment: No such message at my end (`pdflatex`, TeXLive-2018).

Comment: Hmm odd. Must be conflicting with some of my packages then.